# MIPS OR with negative numbers

Tags: mips, boolean-logic, negative-number

So what happens when you OR two negative numbers?  Is it ever guaranteed that whenever you OR a positive with a negative, the result will be positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two's complement:

Whenever you OR any number with a negative number the result is negative. This is because the sign bit is set in the negative number and therefor will be set in the resulting number.